# Where is passenger_max_request_queue_size located in phusion passenger

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, server, passenger

I am getting the below error message

```
The website is under heavy load
```

There are solutions but I don't understand where to change the below parameter in passenger-config.

`passenger_max_request_queue_size`

Please help to find the file location.

I have passenger + Nginx running on my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually put the passenger settings in `nginx.config` because I serve a single app per server. If you use `nginx` for multiple Rails apps, **I think it works** inside the `server { }` block too.

```
load_module /PATH/passenger/libexec/modules/ngx_http_passenger_module.so;
http {
 passenger_root ...

 passenger_min_instances 5;
 passenger_max_pool_size 10;
 passenger_pool_idle_time 600;
 ...
}
```

If you are playing with the settings make sure you know which are for Passenger Enterprise because obviously they won't work if you don't have a license.